# Details of Row Affected in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

I am learning SQL and using SQL Server Management Studio to query the database. When I run an update command, I get a message which displays the number of rows which get updated in the table, e.g. "1 Row affected".

However, I don't get the details of tables which are getting updated. This is required in case when multiple tables are updated on updating single table.

Comment: An `UPDATE` can only ever affect **one table** which is stated right after the `UPDATE` keyword...... not clear what you're looking for here.....

Comment: I came across a database in which a trigger was created which runs on UPDATE command. Suppose I am updating a Table A, then Table B also gets updated automatically which stores the old value and the updated value. Now I receive message of 01 Row Affected twice, one for Table A and one for Table B. But details of table are not shown in Message window. Is it possible to view something like this  '1 Row Affected in Table A' and '1 Row Affected in Table B'.

Comment: OK, I see what scenario you're talking about - but I don't believe there's anything in SQL Server that would support what you're looking for, unfortunately.

Comment: No there's nothing of that sort in SQL. In general, triggers should be avoided for this and many other reasons

Comment: oh... Okay. Thanks for the help then Marc and Nick